# You don't have permission to access some scopes - Gmail oAuth

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-domain-api

My client is trying to connect to gmail API with oauth

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Error: invalid_scope
>
> You don't have permission to access some scopes. Your project is trying to access scopes that **need to go through the verification process**. `{invalid = [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.members.read]}` If you need to use one of these scopes, submit a verification request.
>
> Learn more
>
> Request Details
>   client_id=809629540741-i1g780rbvhjf8r80rkr3vbeon6d5pq3t.apps.googleusercontent.com
>
> That’s all we know.

There is a link to verify domain and the whole verification of your app with Google [here](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification)

My application asking for the following scopes:

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
 https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the wrong scope, you can only use the valid scopes that Google gives us.  This one might be closer to what you are looking for but its under [Domains api](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#plusDomainsv1) and not Gmail.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.read  View your circles and the people and pages in them

Comment: @DalmTo -  which scope is not valid? which one should i replace with plus.circles.read?

Comment: according to the error message you are sending https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.members.read that is not valid

Comment: There is a verification process if you ask for  gmail.readonly. i don't ask for  plus.circles.members.read.   Maybe plus.circles.members.read==  plus.profile.emails.read?

Comment: Check your code again Google doesn't make up its error messages.  You might want to add your code to the question as well scopes should be sent in a list separated by a space.